# Redacting one array with modified instances of another

Tags: arrays, ruby

Hello I have a problem that I am trying to solve.

> Define a method called clean_slate that will take a String representing a record and another String representing a name as arguments. The method returns a string representing the original record, but with every instance of the name replaced with twice as many X's as the name contains characters. If a full name is passed, it will also replace instances where only the first or last name is used with as many X's as the full name contains characters. Your method should not be case sensitive. Assume that the inputs will always be a String. Return the original record if the name isn't found.

So far I have:

```
def clean_slate(record, name)
  name = name.downcase
  split_name = name.downcase.split(" ") #array
  change_name = split_name.map do |letter|
    letter = "X" * 2 * name.length
  end
  record_words = record.downcase.split(" ") #array
  new_record = record_words.map do |word|
   if word.include?(split_name[0] || split_name[1])
     word = change_name
   else 
     word 
   end
  end
 new_record.join(" ")
end

clean_slate("Megan Fox is a talented actress. megan knows sulfoxide is a chemical compound containing a sulfinyl (SO) functional group attached to two carbon atoms. It is a polar functional group. Ms. fox has many talents.", "Megan Fox")
```

I am returning the `record` but I am not getting the last name in the `record` redacted. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix that?

```
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX fox is a talented actress. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX knows sulfoxide is a chemical compound containing a sulfinyl (so) functional group attached to two carbon atoms. it is a polar functional group. ms. fox has many talents."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `record.split.map` you need to check if the `record.downcase` being passed include the first or last value for `split`, but at the same time to check if the `word` in the block is equal to any of those two, so it would be something like:

```
new_record = record.split.map do |word|
  if record.downcase.include?(split_name[0] || split_name[1]) &&
     word.downcase == split_name[0] || word.downcase == split_name[1]
    ...
```

Also if you use `map` over `split_name` to assign the amount of `X`, it'll return an array, and when you do `word = change_name`, it takes the value inside an array, as `['XXXXX']` (e.g), so you need to access the only one value inside:

```
word = change_name.first
```

As it's not needed to initialize a variable not being used inside the block, then just `change_name.first`.

This way, this works:

```
def clean_slate(record, name)
  name = name.downcase
  split_name = name.downcase.split(" ")
  change_name = split_name.map do |letter|
    letter = 'X' * 2 * name.length
  end
  new_record = record.split.map do |word|
    if record.downcase.include?(split_name[0] || split_name[1]) &&
       word.downcase == split_name[0] || word.downcase == split_name[1]
      change_name.first
    else
      word
    end
  end
  new_record.join(" ")
end
```

But it has some things you can improve:

`split(" ")` can be shortened as `split`
`letter = 'X' * 2 * name.length` can be `'XX' * name.length` and 
`change_name = 'XX' * name.length` no need to use map, so
`change_name.first` changes to `change_name`
`join(" ")` prefer single quotes instead double ones

You need a way to simplify the `if` statement inside the `record.map` and still you don't know if the name will be only two words to use `[0]` and `[-1]`.

You could take a look to [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub).

```
def clean_slate(record, name)
  record.gsub(/\b#{name.split.join('|')}\b/i, 'XX' * name.size)
end
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your response and your explanations. I learned new stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner way to implement this. Just compare each word in `record` to `name` and substitute the `X`s.

```
def clean_slate record, name
  names = name.downcase.split
  new_record = []
  record.split.each do |word|
    new_record << word
    if names.include?(word.downcase)
      new_record[-1] = "X" * 2 * name.length
    end
  end
  new_record.join(' ')
end
```

Result:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a talented actress. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX knows sulfoxide is a chemical compound containing a sulfinyl (SO) functional group attached to two carbon atoms. It is a polar functional group. Ms. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX has many talents.
```

Comment: It gives `"XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX is a talented actress. XXXXXXXXXX is super foxy and a great chess player. Ms. XXXXXX has many talents." `when is waiting for `"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a talented actress. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is super foxy and a great chess player. Ms. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX has many talents."`

Comment: Don't worry, that's because Joseph hasn't added the example inputs and expected outputs, you could see the [kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/clean-slate/train/ruby).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task right, I think you can do solution similar to it:

```
def clean_slate(record, name)
  name = name.split.map(&:downcase)
  record = record.split

  record.map do |word|
    if name.include? word.downcase
      word = 'X' * 2 * name.join.length
    else
      word
    end
  end.join(' ')
end

#> clean_slate("Megan Fox is a talented actress. megan knows sulfoxide is a chemical compound containing a sulfinyl (SO) functional group attached to two carbon atoms. It is a polar functional group. Ms. fox has many talents.", "Megan Fox")
#=> "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a talented actress. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX knows sulfoxide is a chemical compound containing a sulfinyl (SO) functional group attached to two carbon atoms. It is a polar functional group. Ms. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX has many talents."
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for your response.